# can i call java method from native code?if so how?

Tags: java-native-interface, native

I have a Java function which can take variable number of parameters and in JNI I am receiving all the parameters in jobjectArray. But the problem is all the parameters available in String type,but originally thy are of different datatype. So in c/c++ converting them to their original type is not possible. So if i could call some other java method which will make these conversions easy for me.is it possible in to call a java method from native code in JNI?

Please help me out. I am really struck at it from a long time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can pass the String as a parameter from native code when you callback the java method using env->NewStringUTF(actual parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a succinct example: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html.

Fundamentally you need to look up native objects representing the class and method you want to call, format your arguments, call the appropriate JNIEnv->CallXXX method, and process the resulting value.

Comment: i am struck again.the problem is when i send primitive datatypes like int as a parameter to the java callback method it was working fine,but when i send String as a parameter it is giving fatal error.can you help me out.

Comment: JNIEXPORT jvoid JNICALL Java_org_bel_MyJMSListenerAction_gsl_1stats_1all_1in_1one
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr)
{

jclass cls=env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID mid=env->GetMethodID(cls,"callback","(Ljava/lang/String;)I");
printf("IN C native,before calling callback method\n");

int t2=env->CallIntMethod(obj,mid,"123");//this string parameter is giving problem

printf("IN C native,after calling callback method\n");
printf("printing t2 value after java callback method:%d",t2);

}

Comment: the java callback method implementation is as follows int callback(String str){

String strin="1234";
int ii=Integer.parseInt(strin);
System.out.println(ii);

System.out.println("The string which has come as a parameter is :"+ str);//here it is giving fatal error

int i=Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.println(i);
return i;
}

Comment: You need to create a Java String based on your C string before Java will be able to read it (as suggested by your "answer" below.